# Sed is not matching a backslash literal or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed

I have a file which has 3 lines:

```
%fddfdffd
\%dffdfd
hello %12345678
```

I need to remove anything after "%" character (inlcuding the "%" character) but not if the "%" begins with a "\".

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
sed -i "s/[^\\]%.*//g"
```

The task is actually working on a latex file to remove the comments using **sed**

The file after using sed should be:

```
\%dffdfd
hello
```

Comment: What should happen if the line contains `\\%`?

Comment: @choroba it shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: The reason why this fails is that the notation `[^\\]%` expects a character before `%` which is not a `\`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest with your three cases:

```
sed '/^%/d; /\\%/b; s/%.*//' file
```

Output:

```
\%dffdfd
hello
```

---

See: `man sed`

Comment: this seems logical; (1) does it start with percent, delete (2) does it contain `\%` jump to the end of the script and do nothing and (3) if we reach this point, remove everything from percent onwards ... This is very clean and simple. There are side cases that are not resolved, but I believe this covers more then 99.9% of the cases!

Comment: Example of side-case: `This line has a % commented out \%-character`

Comment: @kvantour: Yes, it covers the specified cases.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^\])%.*/\1/' file
```

If the line starts with a `%` or `%` follows any character other than `\`, delete the rest of the line.

If as a consequence the line is empty and is also to be deleted, use:

```
sed -E '/^%/d;s/([^\])%.*/\1/' file
```